# Как задать максимальным числом в input то число, которое в span?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, ajax

У меня есть код

```
<input min="0.1" max=""> <span>500</spann>
```

Как сделать так, что инпут брал максимальным числом то, которое в спане находится? оно там будет обновляться в соответствие с API

Comment: Ну а почему бы вам при получении данных от АПИ, сразу не устанавливать нужное значение в input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Обновляем атрибут max input на основе значения из span

```js
        // Получаем ссылки на элементы input и span
        const inputElement = document.getElementById("myInput");
        const spanElement = document.getElementById("maxValueSpan");

        // Функция для установки максимального значения в placeholder
        function setMaxValueAsPlaceholder() {
            const maxValue = parseFloat(spanElement.textContent); // Преобразуем текст span в число
            inputElement.placeholder = "Max: " + maxValue; // Добавляем текст в placeholder
            inputElement.setAttribute("max", maxValue); // Добавляем текст в атрибут max
        }

        // Ваш код для обновления span с API, например:
        function updateValueFromAPI(newValue) {
            spanElement.textContent = newValue;
            setMaxValueAsPlaceholder(); // Вызываем функцию для установки максимального значения в placeholder
        }

        // Пример обновления значения span с API
        updateValueFromAPI(600); // Обновляем span с новым значением
```

```html
 <input type="number" min="0.1" max="" id="myInput" placeholder="">
 <span id="maxValueSpan">500</span>
```